# SQL Express 2019 remote access doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

[remote connection on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZQ76.png)

[sql server auth on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30pl3.png)

[tcp ip on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzyrm.png)

[tcp ip on2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk8CO.png)

[tcp ip on3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TItxD.png)

[tcp ip on4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pIxJ.png)

[firewall on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA1tO.png)

I also have done port fowarding too.

When I try to connect sql express through public ip, it never connects.
When I checked 1435 is open or not, it is closed.
My mysql remote access works perfectly though...

Comment: And the connection string is...?

Comment: Changes to protocol settings don't take immediate effect. After you changed the TCP/IP settings in "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS" did you remember to stop and restart the SQL Express service as well?

Comment: I made connection string as mypublicip,1435

Comment: of course i restarted my sql express